# How to implement the logic without state variables

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift

There are two observables: the first named `activator` emits booleans. The second named `signaler` emits void events. There's a function `f()` which must be called under the next conditions:

If the last event from `activator` is `true`, and event from `signaler` comes, call `f()`. Otherwise (the last `activator`'s event is `false`, or `activator` has not yet emitted anything), "remember" that `signaler` sent the event. As soon as `activator` emits `true`, call `f()` and clear "remembered" flag.

Example:

```
let activator = PublishRelay<Bool>()
let signaler = PublishRelay<Void>()

signaler.accept(()) // activator not emitted yet, just remember that signal came
activator.accept(true) // go to active state. signal is waiting. call f()
signaler.accept(()) // already activated. call f()
activator.accept(false)// go to inactive state
activator.accept(true) // go to active state.
signaler.accept(()) // call f()
activator.accept(false)// go to inactive state
signaler.accept(()) // inactive state, remember that signal came
signaler.accept(()) // still inactive state, remember that signal came
activator.accept(true) // go to active state. there is signal waiting. call f().
signaler.accept(()) // active state. call f().
```

I can achieve the desired behaviour using two state variables `_isActive` and `_waiting`:

```
var _isActive = false
var _waiting = false

activator.bind { isActive in

    self._isActive = isActive
    if isActive && self._waiting {
        f()
        self._waiting = false
    }
}.disposed(by: _bag)

signaler.bind {

    if self._isActive {
        f()
    } else {
        self._waiting = true
    }
}.disposed(by: _bag)
```

The question is: can I implement it without state variables, only by means of reactive operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a state machine, but you can contain the state so you aren't leaving the monad... Something like this:

```
func example(activator: Observable<Bool>, signaler: Observable<Void>) -> Observable<Void> {
    enum Action {
        case signal
        case active(Bool)
    }
    return Observable.merge(signaler.map(to: Action.signal), activator.map(Action.active))
        .scan((isWaiting: false, isActive: false, fire: Void?.none)) { state, action in
            switch action {
            case .signal:
                if state.isActive {
                    return (state.isWaiting, state.isActive, ())
                }
                else {
                    return (true, state.isActive, .none)
                }
            case .active(let active):
                if active && state.isWaiting {
                    return (false, active, ())
                }
                else {
                    return (state.isWaiting, active, .none)
                }
            }
        }
        .compactMap { $0.fire }
}
```

Note how the logic inside the scan closure is the same as the external logic you already have. With the above, you can now do something like this:

```
let activator = PublishRelay<Bool>()
let signaler = PublishRelay<Void>()

example(
    activator: activator.asObservable(),
    signaler: signaler.asObservable()
)
    .bind(onNext: f)
```

Lastly, as a bonus. Here's a unit test proving it works:

```
class RxSandboxTests: XCTestCase {
    func test() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let activator = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(20, true), .next(40, false), .next(50, true), .next(70, false), .next(100, true)])
        let signaler = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(10, ()), .next(30, ()), .next(60, ()), .next(80, ()), .next(90, ()), .next(110, ())])
        
        let result = scheduler.start {
            example(activator: activator.asObservable(), signaler: signaler.asObservable())
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(result.events.map { $0.time }, [220, 230, 260, 300, 310])
    }
}
```